# Checking data integrity of downloaded AWS S3 data when using presigned URLS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-integrity

Occasionally, a client requests a large chunk of data to be transferred to them.
We host our data in AWS S3, and a solution we use is to generate presign URLs for the data they need.

My question:

When should data integrity checks actually be performed on data migration or is relying on TSL good enough...

From my understanding, most uploads/downloads used via AWS CLI will automatically perform data integrity checks.

One potential solution I have is to manually generate MD5SUMS for all files transferred, and for them to perform a local comparison.

I understand that the ETAG is a checksum of sorts, but because a lot of the files are multipart uploads, the ETAG becomes a very complicated mess to use as a comparison value.

Comment: There are a few rare scenarios where a file download could be corrupted, including a mutli-segment downloader and a change of the object during download, so I'd always recommend validating a hash if possible, and to use a secure hash algorithm like sha256, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate "Additional checksums" in AWS S3.

The GetObjectAttributes function returns the checksum for the object and (if applicable) for each part.

Check out this release blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-additional-checksum-algorithms-for-amazon-s3/

Comment: In the context of presigned URLs, do you have to provide the checksum **before** the presigning or is there a way to provide a presigned URL for any file, as long as the user provide the checksum when doing the upload?

Comment: please did you get an answer to your question, I am in the same situation?